# KnowledgeBase article creation mechanism for php, jquery, mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am looking to create a general knowledgeBase for my customer service department which takes information (my thought is from a mysql database) and populates a page with that information based on the content pulled.

Take this site for example:
[ToastMaster](http://www.tuttoaster.com/create-an-ajaxjqueryphp-contact-form/)

I would like to store a primary title, main content, images, etc on my site without actually having to create unique html for each page.

Can anybody make a recommendation for existing suites I could integrate to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of a number of content management systems could be easily used for this. Joomla!, Drupal, etc. Try a few out here: http://php.opensourcecms.com/

Comment: rebuilding our entire site is not necessarily what I was looking to do - only for one particular section of pages on the site itself

Comment: There's no reason to redo the entire site. You can put the whole CMS in a subdirectory called 'kb' or whatever you like. Use the CMS just for your knowledgebase.

Comment: If you want to secure it, and you already have SSL, why will you need another one?